# Sumar totales de un array

Tags: php, array

Quiero devolver la suma de los totales. La idea es que cada clave aparezca solo "una vez" con sus valores totales.

**Entrada**

```
$str = ["B:-1", "A:1", "B:3", "A:5"];
```

**Salida**
A:6,B:2.
Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
$str = ["B:-1", "A:1", "B:3", "A:5"];

function SearchingChallenge($strArr) {
  $i = count($strArr);
  $e = 0;
  While($e < $i){
  return (explode(':', $strArr[$e]));
  }    
}

print_r(SearchingChallenge($str));
//Salida: A:6,B:2.
```

Agradezco algo de ayuda.

Comment: Buenas, por favor explica mejor tu problema, y muestra el código que tienes.

Comment: divide las cadenas por el `:`, ve si la letra coincide y los sumas en variables separadas

Comment: @Excorpion Gracias amigo. Trataré de explicar mejor.

Comment: Intentaste algo?

Comment: Intenta con [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

Comment: @gbianchi Estoy en eso amigo.

Comment: @Charls amigo acabo como lo ves? Estoy tratando con explode.

Comment: @AlJw ese comentario es antes del edit, asi que no, el no lo vió.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

- Dividir cada valor con  `explode()`
- Crear un nuevo array y verificar con `isset` si la clave de la clave del lado izquierdo del explode existe (`A`, `B` ...). Si existe le sumas a esa clave el nuevo valor con `+=`, si no existe, lo agregas.

La función quedaría así:

```
function SearchingChallenge ($mParam) {
    $mData=array();
    foreach ($mParam as $v){
        $mParts=explode(':',$v);
        isset($mData[$mParts[0]]) ? $mData[$mParts[0]] +=$mParts[1] : $mData[$mParts[0]]=$mParts[1];
    }
    return $mData;
}
```

> **Nota:**
>
> A partir de PHP 7, puedes cambiar la línea del ternario
> (`isset($mData) ...`) por una asignación basada en el [*operador de
> fusión de null*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):
>
> ```
> $mData[$mParts[0]] = ($mData[$mParts[0]]??0) + $mParts[1];
> ```

Hagamos una prueba:

```
$str = ["B:-1", "A:1", "B:3", "A:5"];

var_dump(SearchingChallenge($str));
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  ["B"]=>
  int(2)
  ["A"]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Comment: Con PHP7 la linea principal se puede reducir a `$mData[$mParts[0]] = ($mData[$mParts[0]]??0) + $mParts[1];`

Comment: @Sal nunca suelo usar el operador de fusión de null en las respuestas porque no consta la versión de PHP, pero lo he agregado como una nota.

Comment: PHP 5 es una versión [no soportada](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) desde 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esta respuesta te sirva:

```
$str = ["B:-1", "A:1", "B:3", "A:5"];

function SearchingChallenge($strArr) {
    $totalA = 0;
    $totalB = 0;
    
    for ($i=0; $i < count($strArr); $i++) {
        $currentStr = explode(":", $strArr[$i]);

        if ($currentStr[0] === "A") {
            $totalA += (int)$currentStr[1];
        }

        if ($currentStr[0] === "B") {
            $totalB += (int)$currentStr[1];
        }
    }

    return "A:".$totalA.", B:".$totalB;
}

echo SearchingChallenge($str);
```